# How to pause main u.i thread (Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

i don't know if this is the appropriate title for this question but it goes something like this.

I'm running a for loop on my main u.i thread the length is about 1000. Thats quite a lot, shouldn't i do that in an AsyncTask or something since it takes quite a while and may freeze the app? Yes i know but the its important i do on the main thread.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++){ 
      // do stuff
  }
```

Here comes the problem

i have a textview on the UI that i want to set its value when the loop reaches a certain number. But since it'ld compete with the loop that's already running, it won't run till after the loop cycle is completed.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++){

    if(i = 400) {

         textView.setText('blah ' + i);
     }

 }
```

my question is, how do i pause the loop, update the textview and continue the loop afterward whilst on the same thread. I've tried Thread.yield() with no results. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: "Yes i know but the its important i do on the main thread": can you explain why? You identified the problem correctly doing lots of work on the main thread is not a good idea.

Comment: i'm afraid that's not possible, because a thread executes code in a linear fashion and Java doesn't have `goto`. I see some options, like using `break` in the `for` statement, updating the UI and do another `for` again, or properly use other threads to parallelize the `for` loop with updating the UI

Comment: @Henry i don't mind the app freezing, i actually prefer that so one can do anything whilst the loop runs. Now i want to be able to sort of pause my main thread and then setTextview and continue the loop.

Comment: @nandsito can u explain better with an example

Comment: `"Yes i know but the its important i do on the main thread":` no, you're probably wrong about that.

Comment: how do u mean @EpicPandaForce

Comment: There's probably no reason for you to actually do this on the UI thread.

Comment: any reason why you haven't explored using `Timer` with `TimerTask` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `IntentService`, run your loop there in `onHandleIntent`, when you get to your certain number use `sendBroadcast` to your activity, and in `onReceive` update the `textView`.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++){
            if(i == 400) {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.android.myApp.SOME_KEY"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity, `onCreate`:

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.android.myApp.SOME_KEY"));
```

Outside your `onCreate`:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        textView.setText("great");
    }
};
```

Don't forget to add the `Service` to the `Manifest`.

Comment: example please?

Comment: Thanks will try and revert